# Why wont my list amount count update when a new item is added?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've got a base from a source: https://codepen.io/Russbrown/pen/IgBuh?editors=1010 , for a simple to-do list which I will expand upon.

However, when I press the checkbox on an item, the total amount of items needing to be completed does not update.

Here is the code:

**index.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ToDo">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Ryan Shah">

        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

        <title>Todo List - Untitled</title>

        <script src="app/angular.js"></script>

        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="listCtrl">
            <p>Remaining Tasks: {{getItems()}}</p>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in list">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.completed" />
                    <span class="completed-{{item.completed}}">{{item.itemText}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form>
                <input class="add-input" placeholder="I need to..." type="text" ng-model="newItemText" ng-model-instant />
                <button class="add-btn" ng-click="insert()"><h2>Add</h2></button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('ToDo', []);
app.controller('listCtrl', function listCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [
        {
            itemText: 'Hello World',
            completed: false
        },
        {
            itemText: 'Hello :)',
            completed: false
        }
    ];

    $scope.getItems = function() {
        return $scope.list.length;
    };

    $scope.insert = function() {
        $scope.list.push({
            text: $scope.newItemText,
            completed: false
        });
        $scope.newItemText = '';
    };

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.list = _.filter($scope.list, function(item) {
            return !item.completed;
        });
    };
});
```

**N.B.**: I tried using things like `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` on the checkboxes, but that didn't want to work either.

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Which *exact* value isn't updated and you want it to be updated?

Comment: At first your're calling `getItems();`, but it should be `$scope.getItems();`.

Comment: @developer033 removed that line.

Comment: @oryol the {{getItems()}} in the html is not updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working plunker based on your code.](http://plnkr.co/edit/XzpGsjXsmsaIIwHPbnmA?p=preview)

I use a variable items instead of getItems so it updates when I change the value from the controller and added a ng-click to the checkbox.

```
<p>Remaining Tasks: {{items}}</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.completed" ng-click='check(item)'/>
    <span class="completed-{{item.completed}}">{{item.itemText}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in the controller, I added a function check that increments or decrements if when check or uncheck the check box:

```
 $scope.items = $scope.list.length;

    $scope.check = function(item) {
      console.log('check ' + item.completed);
      if (item.completed) {
        $scope.items--;
      } else {
        $scope.items++;
      }
    }
    $scope.getItems = function() {
        return $scope.list.length;
    };

    $scope.insert = function() {
        $scope.list.push({
            text: $scope.newItemText,
            completed: false
        });
        $scope.items++;
        $scope.newItemText = '';
    };
```

Also,in the insert function I increment 'items' when we add a new item, so the total items left is accurate.

For the clear completed items, I added a button that class clear() via ng-click:

```
 $scope.clear = function() {
    console.log('clear');
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {
      $scope.list[i].completed = false;
    }
    $scope.items = $scope.list.length;
  };
```

And the HTML:

```
<button class="add-btn" ng-click="clear()">
    <h2>Clear Completed</h2>
</button>
```

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! I didn't think about the ng-click directive

Comment: any idea how I can fix the item clearing to work? It doesn't clear the items that are completed as hopefully described in the code

Comment: I updated the plunkr added a clearing button that calls clear() via ng-click and rewrote your clear function() to set all the booleans to false and reset the total items. I also updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, the **new** items aren't being shown because you have **it:**

```
text: $scope.newItemText,
```

**instead of:**

```
itemText: $scope.newItemText,
```

A *snippet* working counting the uncompleted items:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [{
        itemText: 'Hello World',
        completed: false
      }, {
        itemText: 'Hello :)',
        completed: false
      }];

      $scope.insert = function() {
        $scope.list.push({
          itemText: $scope.newItemText,
          completed: false
        });
        $scope.newItemText = '';
        // Supposing that all items will be added as uncompleted
        $scope.listTotal++;
      };

      // Initialization of listTotal...
      $scope.listTotal = $scope.list.filter(function(item) {
        return !item.completed;
      }).length;

      $scope.get_total = function(item) {
        // Easy way to increment / decrement the total
        $scope.listTotal += item.completed ? -1 : 1;
      };
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <p ng-bind="'Remaining Tasks: ' + listTotal"></p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.completed" ng-change="get_total(item)" />
        <span class="completed-{{item.completed}}" ng-bind="item.itemText"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form>
      <input class="add-input" placeholder="I need to..." type="text" ng-model="newItemText" ng-model-instant />
      <button class="add-btn" ng-click="insert()">
        <h2>Add</h2></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that issue, but that did not fix the issue at hand! :)

Comment: @madcrazydrumma, my bad, I misunderstood your question. I know you've already accepted the answer, but take a look on my answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code to invoke clear, so add to controller:

```
$scope.$watch('list', $scope.clear, true);
```

And in view

```
<p>Remaining Tasks: {{list.length || 0}}</p>
```